# Auto increment field in table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm using oracle 11g xpress. I have created a simple table. I want that field each time a user inputs data to be incremented by 1, starting from 10000. Can you assist?

My table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE PROG_TITLE 
(
PR_ID       INT         NOT NULL,
PR_TITLE    VARCHAR2(128)   NULL,
PR_INDEX    INT             NULL
);
```

I have added the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE PROG_TITLE 
ADD (CONSTRAINT mykey PRIMARY KEY (PR_ID));
```

And the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE PR_ID START WITH 10001 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Now I can insert values as below (and it works):

```
INSERT INTO PROG_TITLE 
(PR_ID, PR_TITLE, PR_INDEX)
VALUES
(PR_ID.NEXTVAL, 'TEST1', 0);
```

My question is how can I do it **without using NEXTVAL**? How could I edit my query as to insert values only for PR_TITLE and PR_INDEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a **trigger**:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_pt
  2    before insert on prog_title
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.pr_id := pr_id.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into prog_title (pr_title, pr_index)
  2  values
  3  ('test1', 0);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from prog_title;

     PR_ID PR_TITLE               PR_INDEX
---------- -------------------- ----------
     10001 test1                         0

SQL>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!